# Flutter update widgets using firebase remote config

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-remote-config

I am working on a flutter app and I want to update the widgets of a page without pushing new updates on the play store. I have researched a bit on this topic and found that I can use firebase remote config. My idea is to use firebase remote config to fetch the widgets and show them on the app so that I don't need to publish frequent updates for small changes.

For Example, the below code is used to show a circular loading bar:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoadingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoadingWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But now even for the smallest change, let it be changes in color, alignment, or size I need to push a new update to the play store and users need to install the new update in order to reflect the changes.

I want to store the flutter widget in firebase remote config (JSON format) then in the app, it will fetch the JSON data from remote config and show the new changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know that Remote Config only stores primitive values, the problem becomes [how to encode and decode a Flutter widget into a string](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%5Bflutter%5D+how+to+encode+and+decode+a+widget+into+a+string).

I doubt that is going to be simple though, as it'd mean that your application would need to compile the JSON/string into a binary. You'd essentially be implementing something akin to Flutter's Hot Reload for your remote clients, something that'd be pretty cool but is not a built-in feature.

More feasible is to control specific widgets that you already have in your code, as for example [Rubens answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71425120). In a recent sample app I used Remote Config to enable/disable a new feature (a process known as feature flagging) with:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig;

  _MyHomePageState(this.remoteConfig);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: remoteConfig.getBool("chat_enabled") ? 3 : 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.games_outlined)),
                const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.swap_vert_circle_outlined)),
                if (remoteConfig.getBool("chat_enabled")) const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outlined)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              const MyGame(key: Key('game')),
              const Leaderboard(key: Key('leaderboard')),
              if (remoteConfig.getBool("chat_enabled")) const Messageboard(key: Key('messageboard')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: but that would mean I have to create separate key-value pairs for each of the widget's components such as color, size, etc, which will be pretty difficult to manage as if my app has 10-12 screens there would be at least 50-60 key-value pairs moreover I would only have control over the basic features such as color, size, etc.

Comment: even if I manage to decode the JSON to binary, flutter doesn't recognize firebase remote config data as a widget else it recognises it as a int value, double or string etc

Comment: I want to know the correct way how big companies do the job without requiring their app to be updated, Sometimes they change the whole design sometimes they change the whole backend logic, sometimes they change the logo of the app without even updating the app from the play store!!

Comment: @Bishal to change App icons dynamically, you can use  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon currently only iOS is supported

Answer (score 2):

Once your RemoteConfig, you need do add key-value pair to match your needs:

```
key   : value
color : black
```

Thenm fetch the value:

`myRemoteColor = remoteConfig.getString('color')`

Now, your `myRemoteColor` has a string with value `black`.